# Banach spaces and infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let's say I have a Banach space **X** . How can I prove that **X** is Banach if and only if every infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }y_{n}$ with $y_{n}\in$  **X** and $\left \| y_{n} \right \|\leq \frac{1}{2^{n}}$ is convergent?

I know it's trivial in the first direction when **X** is a Banach space, but I have no idea how to prove it when beginning from the convergence argument. Please help.

Comment: You started by **assuming** $X$ is a Banach space, so there's nothing to prove.  Perhaps you meant: "I have a **normed linear** space"...

Answer (score 3):

tAs I commented, I suppose you mean: suppose $X$ is a normed linear space in which every series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n$ with $\|y_n\| \le 2^{-n}$ converges.  You want to show that $X$ is a Banach space, i.e. is complete.

Consider a Cauchy sequence $c_n$ in $X$.  You want to prove that it converges.  Take a subsequence $c_{n_j}$ such that $\|c_{n_j} - c_k\| < 2^{-j}$ for all $k > n_j$.  Consider the series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty {y_j}$ where $y_j = c_{n_j} - c_{n_{j+1}}$.  Then $\|y_j\| < 2^{-j}$, so this converges, say to $s$.   But note that $\sum_{j=1}^k y_j = c_{n_1} - c_{n_{k+1}}$, so the subsequence $c_{n_j}$ converges to $c_{n_1} - s$.   And a Cauchy sequence with a convergent subsequence converges.

Comment: Yes, a normed space is what I meant but forgot to specify. Thank you so much for your help!